# my calender not show dates form start of month when click next month

Tags: android

how to show date from start of month when click on next month or previous month?? suppose current week start of 18 august  when i click on next month september its again show date form 18 to onward not show form begining of month see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHXA0.jpg
when i click next is again form 18 not show form 1st of month

```
          public class HoyahCalendar extends Activity  implements 
      View.OnClickListener        {
public static int mYear;
public static int currentIndex = -1;
public static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;
public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];
String  January="January";
String  February="February";
String  March="March";
String  April="April";
String  May="May";
String  June="June";
String  Jully="Jully";
String  August="August";
String  September="September";
String  October="October";
String  November="November";
String  December="December";
String  Monthname;

 TextView date_today;
 ImageView last_month;
 ImageView next_month;

 ImageView last_week;
 ImageView next_week;


 Button e00;
 Button e01;
 Button e02;
 Button e03;
 Button e04;
 Button e05;
 Button e06;


 Button button;

 String value  ;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getIntent().setAction("Already created");


    date_today = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_today);
    last_month = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.last_month);
    next_month = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_month);
    last_week = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.last_week);
    next_week = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_week);



    e00 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e00);
    e01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e01);
    e02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e02);
    e03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e03);
    e04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e04);
    e05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e05);
    e06 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e06);




    e00.setOnClickListener(this);
    e01.setOnClickListener(this);
    e02.setOnClickListener(this);

    e03.setOnClickListener(this);
    e04.setOnClickListener(this);
    e05.setOnClickListener(this);

    e05.setOnClickListener(this);   






    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    value =String.valueOf(mDay);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {


            AlertDialog alertDialog = new  
   AlertDialog.Builder(HoyahCalendar.this).create(); //Read Update

            alertDialog.setMessage("Date is"+ value);

            alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               }
            });

            alertDialog.show();  
        }

    });





    last_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    next_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth += 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                // mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            }
        }
    });

    next_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 4) {
                    HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 4;
                    // mMonth += 1;
                }

                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
    showOnScreen();

}



           public void showOnScreen() {

    if (mMonth ==1) 
    {
        Monthname="January";
        }
    else 
        if (mMonth ==2) { 
            Monthname="February";
            }

        else
    if (mMonth ==3) { Monthname="March";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==4) { Monthname="April";    }

        else
    if (mMonth ==5) { Monthname="May";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==6) { Monthname="June"; }
        else
    if (mMonth ==7) { Monthname="July";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==8) { Monthname="August";   }
        else
    if (mMonth ==9) { Monthname="September";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==10)    { Monthname="October";  }
    if (mMonth ==11)    { Monthname="November";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==12)    { Monthname="December"; }


    date_today.setText(  Monthname + "  " +mYear);
    e00.setText("" + a[0][0]);


    if(e00.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))



    {e00.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button1 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {
        e00.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    e01.setText("" + a[0][1]);

//  if(e01.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase (String.valueOf(mDay)))

        if(e01.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {
        e01.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Button2 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        e01.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

    e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);
    if(e02.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))

    {e02.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button3 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        e02.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
    e03.setText("" + a[0][3]);


        if(e03.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e03.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button4 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    else
    {
        e03.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    e04.setText("" + a[0][4]);
    if(e04.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e04.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button5 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {
        e04.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    e05.setText("" + a[0][5]);
    if(e05.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e05.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button6 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {
        e05.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

    e06.setText("" + a[0][6]);
    if(e06.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e06.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button7 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    else
    {
        e06.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


}


 public void onRestart() {
     super.onRestart();
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent); 
         }



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()) {
     case R.id.e00:
     // do stuff;
         value=e00.getText().toString();
     break;
     case R.id.e01:
     // do stuff;
         value=e01.getText().toString();
     break;

     case R.id.e02:
         // do stuff;
         value=e02.getText().toString();
         break;
         case R.id.e03:
         // do stuff;
             value=e03.getText().toString();
         break;


         case R.id.e04:
             // do stuff;
             value=e04.getText().toString();
             break;
             case R.id.e05:
             // do stuff;
                 value=e05.getText().toString();
             break;
             case R.id.e06:
                 // do stuff;
                 value=e06.getText().toString();
                 break;

   }

}
    }




 public class ShowCalendar {
 int mYear;
int mMonth;
int mDay;
public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;

    calculateMonthFirstday();
}


public int getmDay() {
    return mDay;
}


public void setmDay(int mDay) {
    this.mDay = mDay;
}


public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay, String time){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    if (time == "next"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 5){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay + 7;
    } else if (time == "last"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay - 7;
    }
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}

public void calculateMonthFirstday(){
    int month, first_day=0;
    if((mYear%4==0 && mYear%100!=0)||(mYear%400==0))
        month=1;
    else
        month=0;

    int y, y12, c, c12, m, d;
    y = mYear%100;
    y12 = (mYear-1)%100; //only for January and February
    c = mYear/100;
    c12 = (mYear-1)/100;
    m = mMonth;
    d = 1;

    switch(mMonth){
    case 1: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(13 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 2: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(14 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 4: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 5: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 6: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 7: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 8: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 9: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 10: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 11: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 12: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    }
    if(first_day<0)
        first_day = 7 - (Math.abs(first_day))%7;//first_day每月第一天星期几
    else
        first_day = first_day%7;

    switch(mMonth){
        case 1: {CalculateCalendar(1,first_day,31);break;}
        case 2: {CalculateCalendar(2,first_day,28+month);break;}
        case 3: {CalculateCalendar(3,first_day,31);break;}
        case 4: {CalculateCalendar(4,first_day,30);break;}
        case 5: {CalculateCalendar(5,first_day,31);break;}
        case 6: {CalculateCalendar(6,first_day,30);break;}
        case 7: {CalculateCalendar(7,first_day,31);break;}
        case 8: {CalculateCalendar(8,first_day,31);break;}
        case 9: {CalculateCalendar(9,first_day,30);break;}
        case 10:{CalculateCalendar(10,first_day,31);break;}
        case 11:{CalculateCalendar(11,first_day,30);break;}
        case 12:{CalculateCalendar(12,first_day,31);break;}
    }
}

public void CalculateCalendar(int month_no, int week_no, int month_days){

    int i, s, targetRow = 0;
    int currentDay;
    if (this.mDay == 0){
        currentDay= HoyahCalendar.mDay;     
    }else {
        currentDay = this.mDay;
    }
    //String[][] a = new String[6][7];
    for (i=0;i<week_no;i++)
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";

    for(i=week_no; i<week_no + month_days; i++){
        s = i - week_no + 1;
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = String.valueOf(s);
        if (s == currentDay && HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = i/7;
        }
    } 
    for (i=0; i<7;i++){
        if (HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i] == null){
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = "";
        }else{
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = 
      HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i];
        }

    }
    for(i=week_no+month_days; i<42; i++)


        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";
}
  }







 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/lightgray"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:height="60sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/last_week22"
        android:layout_width="54sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/meenu" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/last_month"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"

        android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
  </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_today"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_month"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_week22"
        android:layout_width="54sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus" />
</LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >



   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/last_week"
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:background="@drawable/topbar"


        android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
  </ImageView>







 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6">


    <TableRow
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:background="#FEE5AC"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sun"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sunday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/monday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tuesday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/wednesday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thur"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thursday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fri"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/friday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/saturday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:paddingBottom="12dp">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/e00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:textColor="#000000" >

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textColor="#000000" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
</Button>

    </TableRow>



</TableLayout>
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_week"
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"


        android:background="@drawable/topbar"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
    </ImageView>
  </LinearLayout>

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me"
    android:onClick="showAlert"/>
         </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is HoyahCalendar?

Debugging visually what happens is that you are constructing new ShowCalendar(year, month) and then they call calculateMonthFirstDay(), but when is there, they calculate the mDay and put mDAy = HoyahCalendar.mDay, that I don't know what it is. Apparently if this.mDay == 0 is because next/previous month was clicked and then this.mDay = 1, but there is no moment you update the day references.

Try to comment or rename the variables to make help easier.

Comment: i updat emy xml file also just copy and run it actuly isnot my code i copy some where only problem is when i click on previous or next month is not start date from 1s t of month

Comment: Renan Bandeira r u there??

Comment: Yeap, I got ya. But there is no place in code that you update the mDay. I suggest you to put mDay = 1 in if this.mDay == 0 part...